# Sharing databases between web applications design pattern

Tags: mysql, web-applications, database-design, relational-database

I have several different web applications with their own separate databases.  All of these different web applications also use a common database for authentication which contains the list of all of my users and the user's name.  To keep things simple, let just say my application databases are like a forum and they track user posts; in the tables they will store a userID and some post text.

Now the problem I am having is that some of my team members feel that what we are doing is messy and frictional because it kind of a pain how to get my applications to display a users name next to their posts which is a very common task.  First I have to go to the application database and do something like `SELECT userID, postText FROM tblPosts` then I have to take that `userID` and go to the user database and get the actual name with `SELECT name FROM tblUsers WHERE userID = X`.  And then merge data from those two queries together to get it out on the page.

I personally don't mind the way we are doing it as I think it's important to just use a single separate user database for data constancy, but some of my team members want to copy over all of the user names into the local application databases and store the user name next to the userID when recording posts so its super simple to get that information back out.  In the event a user wants to change their name (a very infrequent event and we only have about 100 users) we should just run an update in the common database as well as all of the application databases.

This seems like a common issue people might have.  Can someone please weigh in on the common approaches to dealing with the problem and what we might want to do.

Comment: You're approach is not unreasonable.  "Code is hard" is not a valid reason to denormalize your schema.  It does sound like you'd benefit from abstracting those details away in an object or library, so you can put that data anywhere and the rest of your coworkers/code doesn't have to care.

Comment: I agree with Dave S.  Have everyone write the code once to select the user name from the common table and the user id from the individual tables.  Then they just call their routine to get the user name from the common table.

Answer (score 1):

You have a system with a working single-signon scheme (centralized user identity and authentication).  That's a huge competitive advantage.

You've built it simply and cleanly.  That's even more huge.  This kind of thing is very hard to get right, and you have done that.

(If you were to try to build this with some system like LDAP or Active Directory, you'd have a lot of complex code to maintain.)

Don't let your fellow developers sacrifice that advantage for their personal convenience. If you have to synchronize changes to the user database, you *will* have problems when things get out of sync. It's a *when* question, not an *if* question.

By the way, if your user database and website specific databases are on the same MySQL server, you can do stuff like this to integrate the use of the two different databases. That may meet the needs of your developers.

```
  SELECT u.username, d.opname
    FROM userdatabase.users u
    JOIN website.transaction d ON u.userid = d.userid
```

But if you do this, you'll make it hard to migrate your various website databases to other server machines in the future.